# Simple ARM template not working in Azure Cli

Tags: c#, azure, templates, azure-resource-manager

I have a simple ARM deployment script

```
az deployment group create \
  --name <NAME> \
  --resource-group <ResourceGroup> \
  --template-file template.json \
  --parameters @parameters.json
```

This has a template file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_ftp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "ftp",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_ftp_name')]",
            "location": "ukwest",
            "kind": "V1",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[parameters('connections_ftp_name')]",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/ukwest/managedApis/', parameters('connections_ftp_name'))]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And a parameter file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_ftp_name": {
            "value": "my-name"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this via Azure CLI I get the error

```
az deployment group create \
>   --name DeployMonitorFtp5 \
>   --resource-group middleware.prod.rg \
>   --template-file template.json \
>   --parameters @parameters.json
←[K←[K←[91mDeployment failed. Correlation ID: 1f5b34ad-3105-4dfd-b4ca-d38a98fb800a. {
  "error": {
    "code": "ApiNotFound",
    "message": "The API 'my-name' could not be found."
  }
}←[0m
```

This makes no sense at all given I want to create the resource!

Can someone help please?

Paul

Answer (score 1):

IT is not related to `Az Cli`.
The `api` element should not referenced the parameter `connections_ftp_name`. it should be :

```
"api": {
  "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/ukwest/managedApis/ftp')]"
}
```

When creating a logic app connector, you should also specify the connector, here is a complete sample to create a ftp connector:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "ftpConnectionAPIName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the connection api to access the ftp."
      }
    },
    "ftpServerAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the ftp server address."
      }
    },
    "ftpUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the ftp user name."
      }
    },
    "ftpPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the ftp password."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
      "name": "[parameters('ftpConnectionAPIName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "displayName": "[parameters('ftpConnectionAPIName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "serverAddress": "[parameters('ftpServerAddress')]",
          "userName": "[parameters('ftpUsername')]",
          "password": "[parameters('ftpPassword')]"
        },
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat('subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/ftp')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: ah ok thanks I want my resource to have a specific name, not just ftp, I can use what you have put here :)

Comment: Your connector name will depends on the the `name` property so it will be fine. The `api` element represent an azure api.

Comment: Thanks this worked well.  Ideally I would like to have the other boxes in the ARM template, like Binary Transport, Disable Certificate verificaition, etc but when I generate the template from Azure these are missed?

Comment: Ho you could create your connector manually and use `az rest` to query the ARM API, it will give you more information around the possible properties/values

Comment: ok thanks what else do I put after az rest though?  I managed to get the other check boxes, just trying to find the port number one its not portNumber

Comment: see doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232854/discussion-between-paul-and-thomas).